# Beginner: Index Error - What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python, index-error

As mentioned, I am a beginner and am trying to do short exercises. Unfortunately my online tutor is not able to or unwilling to help me with this (keeps suggesting other ways of doing it).

My task is to check if the first word for the line is 'From ' in which case I need to print the next word (the email address).

For example the file has series of lines like the following

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008    
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.90])  
by frankenstein.mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.3.8) with LMTPA;
From louis@media.berkeley.edu Fri Jan  4 18:10:48 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.97])
```

The code should result with the following output:

```
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
```

I have written the following code to do this:

```
fname = "mbox-short.txt"
f = open(fname,'r')

lines = f.readlines()
i = 0
count = len(lines)

while i < count :
    test = lines[i].split()
    if test[0] == "From " :
        print(test[1])
    i += 1
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\38775\Desktop\py4e\Project 2\email.py", line 10, in <module>
    if test[0] == "From " :
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I just want to understand why this is happening, and how I can correct this. Request you not to take time to share alternatives.

Thanks

Comment: can you put some actual test case and its correct output.

Comment: You could debug your code.

Comment: Hey Rohit, I have made the edits

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong in question itself

Comment: Well it is my first time. Might help if you point it out.

Answer (score 0):

An `IndexError` indicates that you're trying to access some part of a list which doesn't exist (for example, trying to find the 5th value of `[1, 2, 3]`).
It would be good to know a small part of the contents of your file or an example input and your desired output so we can figure out exactly what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a modification of what you have that works:

```
fname = "mbox-short.txt"
f = open(fname,'r')

lines = f.readlines()
i = 0
count = len(lines)


while i < count :
    test = lines[i].strip().split()
    if test[0] == "From":
        print(test[1])
    i += 1
```

After you "strip()" you get this "From email@email.com". You need to tack on a ".split()" to split it into a list of two parts like this 
['From', 'email@email.com'].
Now if test[0] == "From" (if the first word is From) you can print test[1] which will be the second word (the email).

The ".split()" was your mistake because that's what splits the string by spaces or a different character chosen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Made the edit however the error message remains the same. Thanks though

Comment: If the error message is the same you also had to get rid of the space in this "From ", it should just be "From". The spaces are eliminated with .split()

Comment: Try copying and pasting what I have, tested and got your desired output.

Comment: Thanks I had removed the space. And I did copy and paste your code as well. It is so wierd that you're getting the out put while I am unable to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

Turns out the issue was that there were some blank lines in the file and so I needed to nest an if function to keep it moving.

Thanks!